# ObjectOutputStream maximum buffer size

Tags: java, networking

I have a client-server application. java.net APIs are being used both at client and server side. Rather, `java.net.ObjectOutputStream` and `java.net.ObjectInputStream` in tandem, to be specific.

I was trying to find out how `ObjectOutputStream.write` , behaves when underlying TCP layer buffer is full. I wanted to write as much data as possible. But currently I'm scared I may not endup pumping too much data. So to confirm this before writing frequent and huge data, it would have been helpful, if documentation could have mention anything around this.

How much should I write. Till which point I can keep writing. How will do I get to know when it has become too much?

Any know how or a good pointer?

I assume that maximum bandwidth will depend upon underlying physical network efficacy.
Regards,
Mawia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all other streams and writers, ObjectOutputStream blocks while the underlying socket send buffer is full. There is no such thing as 'too much', 'pumping too much data', etc., let alone *not* 'pumping too much data', which is what you profess to be worried about.

Not a real question.

Comment: I got my answer. That is what I wanted to know, is ObjectOutputStream a blocking call or not.And it is blocking.Thanks!

Comment: Btw for your comment about too much data, I think it is a very relevant question, if the TCP Write is not synchronous and write operation is not blocking aswell. Given that, as you said, "Like all other streams and writers, ObjectOutputStream blocks" clear that doubt perfectly.

Comment: @mawia I don't understand what 'doubt' there is to 'clear'. All OutputStreams are blocking. All writes to `OutputStreams` are blocking.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to confirm. Thanks! I was not aware of this universality of blocking to an outputStream.

Comment: You don't need me to confirm that. It's stated in the Javadoc.